# Обновлять документ периодически

Tags: 1с

Есть форма документа, через обработчик ожидания хочу чтобы пока она открыта каждые 60 сек в регистр сведений вносились изменения по её содержимому

1)Если в регистре нет записи с такими реквизитами(Турнир, команда, лига), то создать такую запись.

2) Если есть, то переписать её: пересчитать баллы команды.
В модуле формы

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПриОткрытии(Отказ)
  //some code
  ПодключитьОбработчикОжидания("ПровестиДокумент", 60, Ложь);
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПередЗакрытием(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)
Если Не Объект.Проведен Тогда
    ОтключитьОбработчикОжидания("ПровестиДокумент");
    ПровестиДокумент();
КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПровестиДокумент()
  ПровестиДокументНаСервере();
  ОбновитьОтображениеДанных();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура ПровестиДокументНаСервере()
  Об = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Объект");
  Об.Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Проведение);
КонецПроцедуры
```

В модуле доокумента

```
Процедура ОбработкаПроведения(Отказ, Режим) 
  Запрос = Новый Запрос;
  Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   РезультатыКоманд.Регистратор КАК Регистратор
    |ИЗ
    |   РегистрСведений.РезультатыКоманд КАК РезультатыКоманд
    |ГДЕ
    |   РезультатыКоманд.Турнир = &Турнир
    |   И РезультатыКоманд.Команда = &Команда
    |   И РезультатыКоманд.Лига = &Лига";

  Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Команда", Команда);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Лига", Лига);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Турнир", Турнир);

НаборЗаписей = РегистрыСведений.РезультатыКоманд.СоздатьНаборЗаписей();

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();
Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
    НаборЗаписей.Отбор.Регистратор.Установить(ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Регистратор);
КонецЦикла;
НаборЗаписей.Прочитать();
  Если НаборЗаписей.Количество()>0 Тогда
    Для каждого ЗаписьНабора из НаборЗаписей Цикл
        ЗаписьНабора.Баллы = ПосчитатьБаллы(Лига);
        НаборЗаписей.Записать(Истина)
    КонецЦикла;
  Иначе
    Движения.РезультатыКоманд.Записывать = Истина;
    Движение = Движения.РезультатыКоманд.Добавить();
    Движение.Турнир = Турнир;
    Движение.Команда = Команда;
    Движение.Лига = Лига;
    Движение.Баллы = ПосчитатьБаллы(Лига);
    Движения.РезультатыКоманд.Записать(Истина);
  КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Сейчас 1ска создаёт запись в регистре сведений или меняет существующую при проведении, она там всегда 1 на команду, а вот документы плодятся вместо того, чтобы переписывать один.

Как мне протянуть эту связь правильно?

Чтобы 1ска переписывала существующий документ-регистратор, а не плодила их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если документ не записан, то при выполнении

```
Об = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Объект");
Об.Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Проведение);
```

создается копия нового документа и записывается в базу.

Вам же лучше вместо этого выполнять

```
Записать(Новый Структура("РежимЗаписи", РежимЗаписиДокумента.Проведение));
```

К тому же, эту команду можно вызвать и на клиенте.